# How to execute a drools rule at last?

Tags: drools

I need to execute some rule as the last rule. Any one knows how to do this ? 
Also can a rule change behavior of other rules ? For example can a rule be used to execute certain rule package ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can use the rule attribute salience to give your rules priority. 
You can insert a fact in the Right Hand Side of the rule to make another rules match.
You can also read the documentation for Agenda Groups to select different groups of rules that will be executed at different times.

Hope it helps!

Comment: No problem man, look at the officials docs for more info at drools.org